# Is there a C++/CLI smart pointer project (e.g. scoped_ptr)?

Tags: c++-cli, smart-pointers

Is there a C++/CLI RAII smart pointer class for containment of a native pointer in a managed type?  Just wondering, before I go write my own `clr_scoped_ptr` value class template.

I'm aware of the Microsoft-provided:

- [containment of a managed handle in a native class: `auto_gcroot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177047.aspx)
- [containment of a managed handle in a managed class: `auto_handle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177066.aspx)

The above two are similar to `auto_ptr` or `unique_ptr`.

- [I gave skeleton code for a `counted_handle` here, similar to `shared_ptr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685451/raii-in-c-cli/3686993#3686993)

But all these are for disposing managed ref class instances, not for freeing native objects.

Comment: Interesting. If you write your own `clr_scoped_ptr`, please post it as an answer.

Comment: @sad_man: Please see my code here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1695/2150

Comment: I found this answer helpful as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12674472/929315

Comment: @rotsiser: I see several serous errors in that one looking at it for just a minute. Nevermind that the intended behavior isn't even close to what this question asks for.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I found this question while looking for something to manage a native smart pointer (`shared_ptr` in my case) in a C++/CLI class. I'm sorry if the linked question wasn't helpful to you, but it helped me and I thought it may help others with similar needs who may come across this question. Are you aware of a more suitable solution for use with `shared_ptr`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This one](http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/1356536/msclr-auto_ptr-STL-like-solution.aspx) looks fairly complete, but I'm not looking for silent transfer of ownership ala `auto_ptr`.

---

I've posted my version under a rather permissive license over at [codereview.se](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1695/2150)