# C++/CLI Wrapping a Function that Returns a std::shared_ptr

Tags: .net, c++-cli, wrapper, shared-ptr, mixed-mode

I'm currently wrapping a C++ class with C++/CLI for .NET interoperability following the standard process of holding a native pointer in a managed class. In one instance, I have a native class that has a function like:

```
std::shared_ptr<BaseChannel> channelData(const int RunNumber);
```

I have already begun creating a wrapper class for `BaseChannel`. However, if I pass the raw pointer to the constructor of the managed class, there are no guarantees on the lifetime of the object being pointed to by the managed class. I.e. the shared_ptr could go out of scope and the object will get deleted and the managed class will be left holding a dangling pointer.

What is the common solution for this situation?

**UPDATE**

@Ben: So I wrap the class that holds the method in the above question like so (let's say it is in a native class called `Node` and it is being wrapped in a managed class called NodeRef:

```
ChannelUser^ NodeRef::ChannelData(int runNumber)
{
    // mpNode is native class pointer of type Node held in managed class
    // wrapper called NodeRef
    std::shared_ptr<BaseChannel> spBaseChannel = mpNode->channelData(runNumber);

    // ChannelUser is using clr_scoped_ptr to hold the shared_ptr
    ChannelUser^ channelUser = gcnew ChannelUser(spBaseChannel);
    return channelUser;
}
```

Because the shared_ptr does not have its reference count increased as it is passed to the managed class by reference, does that mean

> that as long as this shared_ptr is in
>   scope, the object it points to will
>   still exist, because its reference
>   count will be at least 1

? (ref [C++ - passing references to std::shared_ptr or boost::shared_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327573/c-passing-references-to-boostshared-ptr))

Comment: The reference count is increased (once by `spBaseChannel`'s constructor, once by `new shared_ptr` in the ChannelUser *ctor-initializer*)... but this stuff isn't going to be thread safe when `std::shared_ptr` isn't.

Comment: @Ben: I updated the last question to indicate my concern properly. However, I think you've answered it in your previous comment anyway. The ref counter gets increased in the ChannelUser ctor-initializer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`shared_ptr` is a native type, and managed objects can't have integral native subobjects.

However, as you note, managed objects can have pointers to native objects.  What you need is a pointer to a `shared_ptr`, which will count as a reference to the `BaseChannel` object and keep it from being freed prematurely.

Of course, there are lots of reasons to use a smart pointer instead of a raw `shared_ptr<BaseChannel>*`.  I've written a smart pointer which should be suitable, you can find it on codereview.stackexchange.com: ["scoped_ptr for C++/CLI (ensure managed object properly frees owned native object)"](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1695/scoped-ptr-for-c-cli-ensure-managed-object-properly-frees-owned-native-object)

---

Example (not compile tested):

```
ref class ChannelUser
{
    clr_scoped_ptr<shared_ptr<BaseChannel>> chan_ptr;

public:
    ChannelUser( shared_ptr<BaseChannel>& chan ) : chan_ptr(new shared_ptr<BaseChannel>(chan)) {}
};
```

This automatically implements `IDisposable` and deletes the `shared_ptr` when `Dispose` or the finalizer runs, which in turn reduces the reference count on the `BaseChannel`.

Comment: +1 - Can you provide an example of how to use your `clr_scoped_ptr` in your answer?

Comment: @Seth: Have done, hope this helps. Let me know if you find any major errors.

Answer (score 18):

Here's a managed `shared_ptr<T>`. You can assign to it directly from a `shared_ptr` and it'll take a copy that it will delete when the managed object is GC'd or disposed.

Examples:

```
m_shared_ptr<CupCake> cupCake0(new CupCake());
m_shared_ptr<CupCake> cupCake1 = new CupCake();
m_shared_ptr<CupCake> cupCake2 = shared_ptr<CupCake>(new CupCake());
m_shared_ptr<CupCake> cupCake3 = make_shared<CupCake>();
shared_ptr<CupCake> cupCake4 = (shared_ptr<CupCake>)cupCake3;
```

Code:

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>

template <class T>
public ref class m_shared_ptr sealed
{
    std::shared_ptr<T>* pPtr;

public:
    m_shared_ptr() 
        : pPtr(new std::shared_ptr<T>()) 
    {}

    m_shared_ptr(T* t) {
        pPtr = new std::shared_ptr<T>(t);
    }

    m_shared_ptr(std::shared_ptr<T> t) {
        pPtr = new std::shared_ptr<T>(t);
    }

    m_shared_ptr(const m_shared_ptr<T>% t) {
        pPtr = new std::shared_ptr<T>(*t.pPtr);
    }

    !m_shared_ptr() {
        delete pPtr;
    }

    ~m_shared_ptr() {
        delete pPtr;
    }

    operator std::shared_ptr<T>() {
        return *pPtr;
    }

    m_shared_ptr<T>% operator=(T* ptr) {
        delete pPtr;
        pPtr = new std::shared_ptr<T>(ptr);
        return *this;
    }

    T* operator->() {
        return (*pPtr).get();
    }

    void reset() {
        pPtr->reset();
    }
};
```

Comment: awesome answer. very underrated.

Comment: the assignment operator of m_shared_ptr isn't deleting p first, isn't that a memory leak?

Comment: I think you're right feel free to edit and fix up this answer

Comment: I came up with a few additional methods I needed 
`:
// Useful for accessing shared_ptr members like 'use_count'
const std::shared_ptr<T> & get() {
    return *pPtr;
}

// Useful when passing to another managed object
std::shared_ptr<T>* share() {
    return new std::shared_ptr<T>(*pPtr);
}

// Allows assignment via std::make_shared
m_shared_ptr<T>% operator=(const std::shared_ptr<T>& t) {
    delete pPtr;
    pPtr = new std::shared_ptr<T>(t);
    return *this;
}
~`

Comment: Brilliant was so about to write something like this myself.  Thanks for saving me some time! :D

Comment: Looks very good. I swapped this to use `boost::shared_ptr` but your last example doesn't work for me (reports it can't convert from `m_shared_ptr<T>` to `shared_ptr<T>`). Any ideas?

Comment: @JonCage Long time no see Mr Cage, afraid I'm not sure of the reason for the problem, perhaps need to be marked as an implicit cast operator.  Haven't been using C++/CLI for a while now.

Comment: OMG. It's you! Ha! ...well I'm not sure what I changed but it magically started working so I can only assume I'd done something stupid ;-)